# Loading ETC1 Textures with alpha using Shader cocos2dx

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, shader

I am following this link:
http://sbcgamesdev.blogspot.in/2013/06/etc1-textures-loading-and-alpha.html

I have two texture, SpinWheel-hd.pkm(rgb) and SpinWheel1-hd.pkm (alpha). I am trying to load an ETC1 texture with alpha.
There resulting image comes white, where in according to the link, it should be my rgb texture with alpha. What am I doing wrong? I am using cocos2dx 2.2.5

Here's my loading code:

```
 rgbTex = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addETCImage("SpinWheel-hd.pkm");
       MainScreen1 = CCSprite::create("SpinWheel-hd.pkm");
   CCSize size1 = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
   MainScreen1->setPosition(ccp(size1.width/2+70, size1.height/2+70));
   this->addChild(MainScreen1);
   alphaTex = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addETCImage("SpinWheel1-hd.pkm");

   alphaTex->setAliasTexParameters();

     CCGLProgram *shader = CCShaderCache::sharedShaderCache()->programForKey("monochromeShader");
    shader->reset();
    /    // Same code as before to initialize the shader
    shader->initWithVertexShaderByteArray(cc_MonoChromeV, cc_MonoChrome);

MainScreen1->setShaderProgram(shader);

MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->addAttribute(kCCAttributeNamePosition, kCCVertexAttrib_Position);
MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->addAttribute(kCCAttributeNameTexCoord, kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords);

MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->link();

MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->updateUniforms();


_maskLocation = glGetUniformLocation( MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->getProgram(),"u_colorRampTexture");
glUniform1i(_maskLocation,1);

_textureLocation = glGetUniformLocation( MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->getProgram(),"u_texture");
glUniform1i(_textureLocation, 0);


MainScreen1->getShaderProgram()->use();


glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rgbTex->getName());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,alphaTex->getName());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Here is my fragment shader

```
 "\n\
  #ifdef GL_ES \n\
  precision mediump float;\n\
   #endif\n\
  uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n\
  uniform sampler2D u_colorRampTexture;\n\
  varying mediump vec2 v_texture;\n\
  void main(void)\n\
  {\n\
       gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_texture, v_texture).rgb, texture2D(u_colorRampTexture, v_texture).r);\n\
  }\n\
";
```

Here's my vertex shader:

```
 "\n\
    attribute vec4 a_position;                                \n\
    attribute mediump vec2 a_texture;\n\
    \n\
    #ifdef GL_ES\n\
   varying mediump vec2 v_texture;\n\
   #else                                                    \n\
   varying vec2 v_texture;                                \n\
  #endif                                                    \n\
  \n\
  void main(void)\n\
  {\n\
       gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;\n\
v_texture = a_texture;\n\
  }\n\
  ";
```

Where am I going wrong? All I see is a pure white image.